# Vector Geo Problem I am lost in.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Question:
There exists positive integers $x, y, z$ where $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$, so that for any Pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)$
$$\begin{pmatrix} x & y & y \\ y & x & y \\ y & y & z \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}$$
is also a Pythagorean triple.

So I tried to bash this question, finding that there should a way to solve it by multiplying the matrices and somehow factoring it.
So I got
$$\begin{pmatrix} xa + y(b+c) \\ y(a+c)+xb \\ y(a+b)+zc \end{pmatrix}$$
then I tried to put it through the Pythagorean theorem, but I could not see a good path to a solution.
Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using a computer to search for possible candidates? Also, there is a trivial solution.

Comment: @TomKern There is no trivial solution since $x$, $y$ and $z$ are required to be *positive*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious thing to do would be to set $(a,b,c)$ to the smallest primitive Pythagorean triples $(3,4,5)$, $(5,12,13)$ and $(8,15,17)$ to get the system of equations
\begin{align}
(3x+9y)^2+(4x+8y)^2 & = (7y+5z)^2\\
(5x+25y)^2+(12x+18y)^2 & = (17y+13z)^2\\
(8x+32y)^2+(15x+25y)^2 & =(23y+17z)^2
\end{align}

and solve the system of equations. This can be done by computer.

However, if there is a solution, we expect to be based in a purely algebraic identity, which means that it will have to work even with *degenarate* Pythagorean triples. So we try setting $(a,b,c)$ equal to $(1,0,1)$ and $(1,0,-1)$, which give us the equations

\begin{align}
(x+y)^2+(2y)^2 & = (y+z)^2\\
(x-y)^2+0^2 & = (y-z)^2
\end{align}

This is a simpler system of equations that we can solve by hand to get the families of solutions:

$x=t$, $y=0$, $z=t$ with $t \in \mathbb R$

$x=t$, $y=0$, $z=-t$ with $t \in \mathbb R$

and

$x=t$, $y=2t$, $z=3t$ with $t \in \mathbb R$

(This solutions are actually the same of the first hard system of equations.)

Since we are interested in solutions with coprime positive integers, the only solution is $x=1$, $y=2$, $z=3$.

It's easy to verify that this is in fact a solution that work with any Pythagorean triple.

Comment: it is also easy enough, taking $A$ to be the matrix with the $x,y,z$ elements, and $D$ the diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $1,1,-1$ to write out the system $A^T DA = D$ in symbols and solve for integer $x,y,z$  Here $A=A^T$ as well...

Comment: I get four integer constraints, $x^2 = 1,$ $ y(2x-y)=0,$  $y(x+y-z)=0,$ $2y^2 - z^2 = -1$

Comment: @WillJagy There's something i'm missing from your solution, may be you can clear it for me. A vector $X$ is a Pythagorean triple iff $X^TDX = 0$, and we want to find $A$ such that $X^TDX = 0$ implies $X^TA^T DA X = 0$. So obviously $A^TDA = D$ is a sufficient condition, but is not necessary. So in this case, you got lucky that this give you the solution, right?

Comment: Well, for $D$ the identity matrix, any integer matrix $A$ takes the origin to the origin, and that is all the real null vectors. For  indefinite.....